# catkin can't find geometry_msgs even though it's on CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: catkin, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run `sudo apt install -y ros-geometry-msgs`, but when I try to build my project with it, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:271 (message):

Could not find 'share/geometry_msgs/cmake/geometry_msgs-msg-paths.cmake'
 (searched in '/home/tjpowell/Robot_files/RobotCodeRospy/test3/devel;
/home/tjpowell/Robot_files/RobotCodeRoscpp/test3/devel;/opt/ros/noetic').
```

`echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`:

```
/home/tjpowell/Robot_files/RobotCodeRospy/test3/devel:
/home/tjpowell/Robot_files/RobotCodeRoscpp/test3/devel:
/opt/ros/noetic:
/usr/share/geometry_msgs/cmake
```

When I print `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` at the beginning of `CMakeLists.txt` using `cmake_print_variables`, it gives the above value as well, with `/usr/share/geometry_msgs/cmake`.

`ls /usr/share/geometry_msgs/cmake`:

```
geometry_msgs-msg-extras.cmake  geometry_msgs-msg-paths.cmake  geometry_msgsConfig-version.cmake  geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
```

`package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                                                                              
<package format="2">                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<name>test3_abhi</name>                                                                                                                                                                                            
<version>0.0.0</version>                                                                                                                                                                                           
<description>The test3_abhi package</description>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>                                                                                                                                                                        
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                 
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                 
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>                                                                                                                                                                   
<build_export_depend>message_runtime</build_export_depend>                                                                                                                                                       
<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>                                                                                                                                                                  
<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>                                                                                                                                                                   
<build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>                                                                                                                                                                
<exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                  
<exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                   
<exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                   
<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<export>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
</export>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
</package>
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)                                                                                                                                                                              
project(test3_abhi)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
include(CMakePrintHelpers)                                                                                                                                                                                         
set (geometry_msgs_DIR "/usr/share/geometry_msgs/cmake")                                                                                                                                                           
cmake_print_variables(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS                                                                                                                                                                              roscpp                                                                                                                                                                                                             rospy                                                                                                                                                                                                              std_msgs                                                                                                                                                                                                           message_generation                                                                                                                                                                                                 geometry_msgs                                                                                                                                                                                                    )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                        ##   * add a build_depend                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
add_service_files(                                                                                                                                                                                                   FILES                                                                                                                                                                                                              TSP.srv                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             )              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here                                                                                                                                          
generate_messages(                                                                                                                                                                                                   DEPENDENCIES                                                                                                                                                                                                       std_msgs                                                                                                                                                                                                           geometry_msgs                                                                                                                                                                                                    )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

catkin_package(                                                                                                                                                                                                      INCLUDE_DIRS include                                                                                                                                                                                             #  LIBRARIES test3_abhi                                                                                                                                                                                              CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs geometry_msgs message_runtime                                                                                                                                               #  DEPENDS system_lib                                                                                                                                                                                              )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                 include_directories(                                                                                                                                                                                               # include                                                                                                                                                                                                            ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}                                                                                                                                                                                           )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS                                                                                                                                                                                             ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}                                                                                                                                                                                          "-fopenmp")                                                                                                                                                                                                    

add_compile_options(                                                                                                                                                                                                   -I/opt/ros/noetic/include -I/usr/local/include/dynamixel-sdk)                                                                                                                                                  

add_executable(test3_printemo src/test3_printemo.cpp include/abhi.cpp)                                                                                                                                             

target_link_libraries(test3_printemo ${catkin_LIBRARIES} #${OpenCV_LIBS}                                                                                                                                               Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui Qt5Test Qt5Concurrent Qt5Core                                                                                                                                                                    dxl_x64_cpp boost_system pcl_visualization                                                                                                                                                                         pcl_common pthread phidget21                                                                                                                                                                                       realsense2 hdf5_serial                                                                                                                                                                                             blas hdf5_serial_hl boost_filesystem                                                                                                                                                                               boost_thread opencv_highgui                                                                                                                                                                                        opencv_ximgproc opencv_photo                                                                                                                                                                                       opencv_calib3d opencv_imgcodecs                                                                                                                                                                                    opencv_imgproc opencv_core)      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
add_executable(tsp src/TSPSrv.cpp include/abhi.cpp)                                                                                                                                                                

target_link_libraries(tsp ${catkin_LIBRARIES} #${OpenCV_LIBS}                                                                                                                                                          Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui Qt5Test Qt5Concurrent Qt5Core                                                                                                                                                                    dxl_x64_cpp boost_system pcl_visualization                                                                                                                                                                         pcl_common pthread phidget21                                                                                                                                                                                       realsense2 hdf5_serial                                                                                                                                                                                             blas hdf5_serial_hl boost_filesystem                                                                                                                                                                               boost_thread opencv_highgui                                                                                                                                                                                        opencv_ximgproc opencv_photo                                                                                                                                                                                       opencv_calib3d opencv_imgcodecs                                                                                                                                                                                    opencv_imgproc opencv_core)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408502/catkin-can%27t-find-geometry_msgs-even-though-it%27s-on-cmake_prefix_path/) by [TheAlmightySand](https://answers.ros.org/users/101969/thealmightysand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-26**:
@TheAlmightySand: Welcome to ROS Answers. You do not need to close your question upon receiving the answer. Instead, you upvote and click on the checkmark ✓ to accept the correct answer. You have already accepted the correct answer below. Therefore, please ignore my message. Just remember not to close your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple things which confuse me about your post:

1. you don't say anything about the OS you're using (although it's likely a Debian/Ubuntu (derivative), because of the use of `apt`)
2. you tagged this `noetic`, but then install `ros-geometry-msgs`, which is **not** a package in ROS Noetic (as that would be called `ros-noetic-geometry-msgs`)
3. you show paths to `/usr`, which are not normally paths used by / present in ROS distribution packages
4. you *also* show paths to `/opt/ros/noetic`, which is indeed where normal ROS Noetic package would end up
5. you appear to be manually specifying absolute include paths using `add_compile_options(..)`. That's never really a good idea, but probably an attempt to get things working?

All-in-all, it's a bit messy.

Could it be you've (inadvertently) installed some [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages)?

If so, and you did not intent to: I'd suggest removing them and installing their Noetic counterparts.

If this is an OS that doesn't have binary packages of ROS Noetic and you used the upstream packages on purposes: don't mix-and-match. It doesn't work (reliably) as you've found out.

Also: don't manually manipulate your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. If you find you have to do that, something else is not configured correctly. Manually changing it is not the solution.

PS: and pedantic, but: "**CMake** can't find geometry_msgs [..]", not "Catkin can't find [..]". It's all CMake. This has nothing to do with Catkin.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheAlmightySand](https://answers.ros.org/users/101969/thealmightysand/) on 2022-10-25**:
The issue was the ros-geometry-msgs package. Uninstalling that and installing ros-**noetic**-geometry-msgs, like you said (and then adding it as a dependency in my package.xml) fixed the issue. Thank you!